# Android Map V2 map load in one activity but not in other two

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I am new with android map api v2. I am trying to load map in 3 different activities(on some user action), one by one. Map loads fine in 1 activity but remaining to only show the gray boxes only with zoom buttons.

Following is XML layout(map_view.xml) i am including in three different layouts using include tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapLocationDetail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/transparent_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@android:color/transparent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRefresh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_green_small"
        android:text="Direction"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Following is the code which is loading map properly in one activity. but not in other 2.

```
package com.nthreads.out2b.activity.places;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.nthreads.out2b.Out2B;
import com.nthreads.out2b.R;

public class LocationDetailActivity extends Out2B {
static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
private GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_detail);

    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapLocationDetail))
            .getMap();
    Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
            .title("Hamburg"));
    Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(KIEL)
            .title("Kiel")
            .snippet("Kiel is cool")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.map_resturant_marker)));

    // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
}
```

Map loading properly : 
[image]

Not loading properly :
[image]

Comment: You gave code that is working fine, I think. Where is the code for Activity in which map is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some alternatives of this issue. Your code is looking fine, its not something wrong with the code or include tag. The main issue are Tabs, i guess your map is working fine where you loading it in activity and not working in tabs. So what i suggest is to use view pager or make your own controls to show as tabs. Maps will work in this way.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapLocationDeatail);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Try this in these activities.